# Yahoo Messenger Library C#

Tags: c#, yahoo-messenger

I'm planning to create Yahoo Messenger bot using C#, but until now, I cant find a reliable Yahoo Messenger, except in PHP, Java and C++. Is there a library like this in C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I just created a working YMSG library for a chat client (not a bot) in C#, so I can tell you there's nothing out there that works for YMSG version 16 for C#.    (sorry it's for the company for which I work, I can't release any source)

But all is not lost.  With the exception of the authentication procedure, the protocol is **dirt** simple to understand.  Two good things:

1. The authentication procedure has been deciphered: http://www.carbonize.co.uk/ymsg16.html.  It uses an HTTP call, but that's simple in C#.  The only part you might struggle with is the hashing of challenge/response strings. Unfortunately there's no way to implement it in stages - it either works or it doesn't
2. WireShark has a dissector for YMSG that's pretty thorough.  Helped me a lot.

(Note that this covers the IM portion of Yahoo YIM - I have no idea how the chat "rooms" work)

Good luck!

Eric

Comment: I give up...I lookin other solutions such as with Java libs. Thanks anyway

Comment: Hmmm that's too bad - like I said it's really super simple to understand, it's only the authentication procedure that I had a few problems with.