# Working with yahoo messenger using c# application

Tags: c#

**Hi**
I want to know how I can working using c# application with yahoo messenger I'm going to create an application with the following specification :
1- my application is standalone application and work on independent computer
2- the application should listen to yahoo messenger and when someone's status change to online send pm for him/her. 
I want to find a way to programming I mean programming method or some psudocode I think there are a lot of samples for java but I need some for C#.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191980/yahoo-messenger-library-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of no existing YMSG protocol implementation in C#. If you're determined for your application to be in C# your best bet is to pick one of the java implementations and try to port it. One other option is [http://ycoderscookbook.com/](http://web.archive.org/web/20101114202510/http://www.ycoderscookbook.com/tutorials/index.html/). The site has a number of sample programs which may point you in the right direction. The YCC Trainer is in VB.NET but could be easily converted to C# using .NET Reflector.

Your description sounds eerily like a spam bot. If this is your intention keep in mind that:

- Yahoo's [Terms of Service](http://info.yahoo.com/legal/us/yahoo/messenger/messengertos/messengertos-279.html) prohibit this*
- IM spamming is easily blocked by using a whitelist/blacklist

*Then again they also prohibit reverse engineering of their protocol and unauthorized use by thirdparty programs... considering the number of Y-Messenger clients out there they don't enforce this very well.

Comment: No not spam I just want to auto responser for some customer