# Having connection to Latest Yahoo Messenger Protocol in C#

Tags: c#, network-programming, yahoo

I want to program a simple GUI to connect to Yahoo! Protocol and act as a messengers which use them now. So, could any one describe Yahoo! Protocol structure ( Please help me in using of latest version of this protocol ).

Thanks about your attention.

Comment: As your question is, it isn't specific enough.  Try something, and if necessary, come back when you have a specific problem that we can answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you will find these links helpful as they describe several aspects the Yahoo! Protocol...

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ycs/ 
http://www.ycoderscookbook.com/ 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/YCC_Trainer.aspx 
[Yahoo Messenger Library C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191980/yahoo-messenger-library-c/1192029#1192029) 
http://www.carbonize.co.uk/ymsg16.html 
http://libyahoo2.sourceforge.net/ 
http://www.venkydude.com/articles/yahoo.htm

some general information http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Messenger_Protocol