# Connect to yahoo messenger via XMPP

Tags: c#, xmpp

I'm very new to XMPP and am working on a chat client. Currently I'm using jabber-net to help me build it and am able to connect to Google Talk from it. I'm trying to connect to yahoo but am unable to.

```
        User = txtUserName.Text;
        Pwd = txtPassword.Text;
        pnlCredentials.Enabled = false;
        jabberClient1.User = User;
        jabberClient1.Server = "chat.live.yahoo.com";
        jabberClient1.Port = 5050;//i believe this is the port
        jabberClient1.Password = Pwd;
        jabberClient1.AutoRoster = true;
```

This is how I'm attempting to connect to yahoo but continues to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo does not support XMPP.  This question ([Yahoo Messenger Library C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191980/yahoo-messenger-library-c-sharp)) might provide you a starting point.